# Fourier transform of $\cos(\omega)$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, transformation

We have
$$\begin{align}f(t) &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos(\omega)e^{j\omega t} \ dt \\ &=\frac{e^{j\omega t}}{2\pi(1-t^2)}\{jt\cos(\omega)+\sin(\omega)\}_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \\ &=\frac{1}{\pi(1-t^2)}\cos\left(\frac{\pi t}{2}\right)\end{align}$$

How did we get the $jt\cos(\omega) + \sin(\omega)$
term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately you're asking how to do
$$\int \cos \omega\ e^{j \omega t} \, d\omega = \frac{e^{j \omega t}}{1-t^2} (jt \cos \omega + \sin \omega).$$
But this is just a standard application of integration by parts.

Comment: oh.............

Comment: I'm happy to add detail on how to perform this integration, but it shouldn't be too difficult if you try. Alternatively you can write $2 \cos \omega = e^{j \omega} + e^{-j \omega}$ and calculate it like that instead.